# How to get facebook video profile by FQL

Tags: facebook, forms-authentication, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(fb);
    if (!auth.IsAuthorized())
    {
        var url = auth.GetLoginUrl(new HttpRequestWrapper(Request));
        var content = CanvasUrlBuilder.GetCanvasRedirectHtml(url);
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        Response.Write(content);
        Response.End();
        return;
   }
   dynamic me = fb.Api("/me");
   if (fb != null)
   {
        FacebookID = fb.Session.UserId;
        AccessToken = fb.Session.AccessToken;
   }    
   FacebookApp fbapp = new FacebookApp(AccessToken);
   dynamic videos = fbapp.Fql("SELECT vid, owner FROM video WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");    
   foreach (dynamic v in videos)
   {
       // Can't return videos here
   }    
}
```

But there is no videos when I execute this fql.

But with this code above, I use another fql, such as:

```
dynamic fanpages = fbapp.Fql("SELECT page_id, name, pic_big, type, page_url FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() or uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))");

foreach (dynamic fan in fanpages)
{
// Can return fan page in here
}
```

The problem I think is AccessToken. This AccessToken can't have permission when fql video table, but can have permission when fql fan pages.

Anybody please help me.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

With the new [graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/), you access it via an URL instead of using fbapp.fql() calls. It is quite straightforward. Help this helps